# Synonym request: [ftl] as synonym for [ftl-faster-than-light]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can [ftl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ftl) be created to act as a synonym for [ftl-faster-than-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ftl-faster-than-light)? It's the standard usage to refer to the game.

Comment: Wouldn't such a thing be unnecessary, given "ftl-faster-than-light" would both A) be found in google searches since dashes are not parsed, and B) come up when you type "ftl" in the tag box/search box?

Comment: I'm typing ftl into the search box right now. Doesn't come up.

Comment: [This is what he meant.](http://i.imgur.com/zk3on.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your request has been completed.